# Is there a Javascript event that is fired when soft keyboard is opened in a phonegap application?

Tags: javascript, cordova, dom-events, android-softkeyboard

Using PGB can my Javascript application know when the keyboard has opened?

I have a page that has a textbox a little bit below the pages vertical middle.
When the user sets focus into that textbox, the keyboard opens and covers all but the topmost 2 or 3 pixels of the textbox.

If I could know when the keyboard opened and what element has the focus I could probably scroll them some more manually...

Comment: Did my answer help you or do you have any question to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about phonegap, but I had a similar problem in a webapp for Android.

When the virtual keyboard is opened (on Android devices), the `window.onresize` event is called. You can store the original height of the viewport when the app is starting, so you know later on if the virtual keyboard is opened or closed (based on the current height of the viewport).

Anyway, as you have the problem on an input element, you could also use the `onfocus` and `onblur` events for it.

Comment: I some how missed your answers, my apologies. It sounds like a good idea and I might try to use it in the future. I will probaby create some class to track all resize events (remembering the largest size seen) and try to infer what the current situation is based of the difference from current size to max size.

Answer (score 1):

After you get onDeviceReady in PhoneGap then try:

```
document.addEventListener("hidekeyboard", keyboardHide, false);
document.addEventListener("showkeyboard", keyboardShow, false);
```

You may also need:

```
<plugin name="SoftKeyBoard" value="org.apache.cordova.plugins.SoftKeyBoard" />
```

in your res/xml/plugins.xml Android project file.

Comment: thanks, this sounds like a good idea, however it would mean that I can not use phone gap build. (at least until they add some general support for plugins).

Comment: If at some point in the future general plugin support would be added to PGB this Q would probably qualify to be accepted instead of the one I just accepted.

Answer (score 1):

You will also need to ensure in your Android manifest that you have:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

in the  node.

Essentially as **w4rumy** mentions this will basically trigger the window.onresize event

Comment: As I am using phone gap build and not phongap directly - I have no control over this menifest AFAIK. I will probably have to test if I get the resizeEvent or not if and when I will decide to use this. Thanks for the comment.